# Problem installing Dual Band USB Adapter 2.4/5GHz Wi-Fi on Ubuntu 18.04.4

Tags: networking, drivers, network-bridge, additional-drivers, wifi-direct

- 

**DUAL BAND USB ADAPTER 2.4/5GHz 1200(866+300)Mbps WIRELESS SPEED WITH 802.11ac**

So lately I bought Dual Band USB Adapter with the driver on the CD to install on Windows, Mac, and Linux.

I'm using **Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS** - 64-bit

**1.**
After I connected the adapter into USB port, I checked the port typing in terminal `lsusb` and I got the following:

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

**2.**
`sudo dkms status` and then I got nothing after that.

**3.**
And then I went to install Wi-Fi 2.4GHz in the folder called ( *RTL81888192EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519* )
that is in the CD, typing in the terminal `chmod +x install.sh` and then `sudo ./install.sh` and I got the following result:

```
##################################################
Realtek Wi-Fi driver Auto installation script
Novembor, 21 2011 v1.1.0
##################################################
Decompress the driver source tar ball:
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519.tar.gz
rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/ (all files)

Authentication requested [root] for make clean:
cd hal/OUTSRC/ ; rm -fr */*.mod.c */*.mod */*.o */.*.cmd */*.ko
cd hal/OUTSRC/ ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd hal/led ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr */*/*.mod.c */*/*.mod */*/*.o */*/.*.cmd */*/*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr */*.mod.c */*.mod */*.o */.*.cmd */*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd core/efuse ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd core ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep/linux ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd platform ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
rm -fr Module.symvers ; rm -fr Module.markers ; rm -fr modules.order
rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko *~
rm -fr .tmp_versions
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-101-generic/build M=/home/luisito/Documents/RTL81888192EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-101-generic'
CC [M]  /home/luisito/Documents/RTL81888192EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /home/luisito/Documents/RTL81888192EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/include/osdep_service.h:41:0,
                 from /home/luisito/Documents/RTL81888192EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /home/luisito/Documents/RTL81888192EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/home/luisito/Documents/RTL81888192EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/include/osdep_service_linux.h: In function ‘_init_timer’:
/home/luisito/Documents/RTL81888192EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/include/osdep_service_linux.h:253:8: error: ‘_timer {aka struct timer_list}’ has no member named ‘data’
  ptimer->data = (unsigned long)cntx;
        ^~
/home/luisito/Documents/RTL81888192EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/include/osdep_service_linux.h:254:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’; did you mean ‘_init_timer’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  init_timer(ptimer);
  ^~~~~~~~~~
  _init_timer
In file included from /home/luisito/Documents/RTL81888192EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/include/drv_types.h:32:0,
             from /home/luisito/Documents/RTL81888192EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/home/luisito/Documents/RTL81888192EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/include/osdep_service.h: In function ‘thread_enter’:
/home/luisito/Documents/RTL81888192EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/include/osdep_service.h:342:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘allow_signal’; did you mean ‘do_signal’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  allow_signal(SIGTERM);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
  do_signal
/home/luisito/Documents/RTL81888192EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/include/osdep_service.h: In function ‘flush_signals_thread’:
/home/luisito/Documents/RTL81888192EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/include/osdep_service.h:352:6: error: implicit declaration of function ‘signal_pending’; did you mean ‘timer_pending’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  if (signal_pending (current))
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      timer_pending
/home/luisito/Documents/RTL81888192EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/include/osdep_service.h:354:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘flush_signals’; did you mean ‘do_signal’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   flush_signals(current);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
   do_signal
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:330: recipe for target '/home/luisito/Documents/RTL81888192EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/luisito/Documents/RTL81888192EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
Makefile:1577: recipe for target '_module_/home/luisito/Documents/RTL81888192EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/luisito/Documents/RTL81888192EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-101-generic'
Makefile:1318: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################
```

It seems that the file ***rtw_cmd.o*** does not exist in the folder, therefore it has been failed.

**4.**
And finally I went to install Wi-Fi 5GHz in the folder called ( *RTL8821AU_Linux_v5.2.6_21981_COEX20170206-6760.20170407* ) that is in the CD, typing in the terminal `chmod +x install.sh` and then `sudo ./install.sh` and I got the following result:

```
##################################################
Realtek Wi-Fi driver Auto installation script
Novembor, 21 2011 v1.1.0
##################################################
Decompress the driver source tar ball:
    rtl8821AU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.6_21981.20170407_COEX20170206-6760.tar.gz
rtl8821AU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.6_21981.20170407_COEX20170206-6760/ (all files)

Authentication requested [root] for make clean:
#make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-101-generic/build M=/home/luisito/Documents/RTL8821AU_Linux_v5.2.6_21981_COEX20170206-6760.20170407/driver/rtl8821AU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.6_21981.20170407_COEX20170206-6760 clean
cd hal ; rm -fr */*/*/*.mod.c */*/*/*.mod */*/*/*.o */*/*/.*.cmd */*/*/*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr */*/*.mod.c */*/*.mod */*/*.o */*/.*.cmd */*/*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr */*.mod.c */*.mod */*.o */.*.cmd */*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd core/efuse ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd core ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep/linux ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd platform ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
rm -fr Module.symvers ; rm -fr Module.markers ; rm -fr modules.order
rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko *~
rm -fr .tmp_versions
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-101-generic/build M=/home/luisito/Documents/RTL8821AU_Linux_v5.2.6_21981_COEX20170206-6760.20170407/driver/rtl8821AU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.6_21981.20170407_COEX20170206-6760  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-101-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/luisito/Documents/RTL8821AU_Linux_v5.2.6_21981_COEX20170206-6760.20170407/driver/rtl8821AU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.6_21981.20170407_COEX20170206-6760/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /home/luisito/Documents/RTL8821AU_Linux_v5.2.6_21981_COEX20170206-6760.20170407/driver/rtl8821AU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.6_21981.20170407_COEX20170206-6760/include/osdep_service.h:47:0,
                 from /home/luisito/Documents/RTL8821AU_Linux_v5.2.6_21981_COEX20170206-6760.20170407/driver/rtl8821AU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.6_21981.20170407_COEX20170206-6760/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /home/luisito/Documents/RTL8821AU_Linux_v5.2.6_21981_COEX20170206-6760.20170407/driver/rtl8821AU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.6_21981.20170407_COEX20170206-6760/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/home/luisito/Documents/RTL8821AU_Linux_v5.2.6_21981_COEX20170206-6760.20170407/driver/rtl8821AU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.6_21981.20170407_COEX20170206-6760/include/osdep_service_linux.h: In function ‘_init_timer’:
/home/luisito/Documents/RTL8821AU_Linux_v5.2.6_21981_COEX20170206-6760.20170407/driver/rtl8821AU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.6_21981.20170407_COEX20170206-6760/include/osdep_service_linux.h:288:8: error: ‘_timer {aka struct timer_list}’ has no member named ‘data’
  ptimer->data = (unsigned long)cntx;
        ^~
/home/luisito/Documents/RTL8821AU_Linux_v5.2.6_21981_COEX20170206-6760.20170407/driver/rtl8821AU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.6_21981.20170407_COEX20170206-6760/include/osdep_service_linux.h:289:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’; did you mean ‘_init_timer’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  init_timer(ptimer);
  ^~~~~~~~~~
  _init_timer
In file included from /home/luisito/Documents/RTL8821AU_Linux_v5.2.6_21981_COEX20170206-6760.20170407/driver/rtl8821AU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.6_21981.20170407_COEX20170206-6760/include/drv_types.h:32:0,
                 from /home/luisito/Documents/RTL8821AU_Linux_v5.2.6_21981_COEX20170206-6760.20170407/driver/rtl8821AU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.6_21981.20170407_COEX20170206-6760/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/home/luisito/Documents/RTL8821AU_Linux_v5.2.6_21981_COEX20170206-6760.20170407/driver/rtl8821AU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.6_21981.20170407_COEX20170206-6760/include/osdep_service.h: In function ‘thread_enter’:
/home/luisito/Documents/RTL8821AU_Linux_v5.2.6_21981_COEX20170206-6760.20170407/driver/rtl8821AU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.6_21981.20170407_COEX20170206-6760/include/osdep_service.h:375:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘allow_signal’; did you mean ‘do_signal’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  allow_signal(SIGTERM);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
  do_signal
/home/luisito/Documents/RTL8821AU_Linux_v5.2.6_21981_COEX20170206-6760.20170407/driver/rtl8821AU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.6_21981.20170407_COEX20170206-6760/include/osdep_service.h: In function ‘flush_signals_thread’:
/home/luisito/Documents/RTL8821AU_Linux_v5.2.6_21981_COEX20170206-6760.20170407/driver/rtl8821AU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.6_21981.20170407_COEX20170206-6760/include/osdep_service.h:385:6: error: implicit declaration of function ‘signal_pending’; did you mean ‘timer_pending’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  if (signal_pending(current))
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      timer_pending
/home/luisito/Documents/RTL8821AU_Linux_v5.2.6_21981_COEX20170206-6760.20170407/driver/rtl8821AU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.6_21981.20170407_COEX20170206-6760/include/osdep_service.h:386:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘flush_signals’; did you mean ‘do_signal’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   flush_signals(current);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
   do_signal
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:330: recipe for target '/home/luisito/Documents/RTL8821AU_Linux_v5.2.6_21981_COEX20170206-6760.20170407/driver/rtl8821AU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.6_21981.20170407_COEX20170206-6760/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/luisito/Documents/RTL8821AU_Linux_v5.2.6_21981_COEX20170206-6760.20170407/driver/rtl8821AU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.6_21981.20170407_COEX20170206-6760/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
Makefile:1577: recipe for target '_module_/home/luisito/Documents/RTL8821AU_Linux_v5.2.6_21981_COEX20170206-6760.20170407/driver/rtl8821AU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.6_21981.20170407_COEX20170206-6760' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/luisito/Documents/RTL8821AU_Linux_v5.2.6_21981_COEX20170206-6760.20170407/driver/rtl8821AU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.6_21981.20170407_COEX20170206-6760] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-101-generic'
Makefile:1877: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################
```

It also seems that the file ***rtw_cmd.o*** does not exist in that folder, therefore it has also been failed.

**-**
So could anyone fix the files ***rtw_cmd.o*** in both folders of Wi-Fi 2.4GHz and 5GHz, please?

The folders are in the following link: [Dual Band USB Adapter Wifi for Linux](https://yadi.sk/d/GaWd9QMkKGYGtA)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, be certain that the necessary prerequisites are installed:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall build-essential dkms git
git clone https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu.git
cd rtl88x2bu 
VER=$(sed -n 's/\PACKAGE_VERSION="\(.*\)"/\1/p' dkms.conf) 
sudo rsync -rvhP ./ /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-${VER} 
sudo dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER} 
sudo dkms build -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER} 
sudo dkms install -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER} 
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: Lately I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS from 19.04 LTS and I also upgraded to the kernel 5.8.13, I followed your steps but when I typed `sudo dkms build -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}` I got the result:

Comment: `Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...`
`Building module:`
`cleaning build area...`
`make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=5.8.13-050813-generic KVER=5.8.13-050813-generic src=/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.6.1......(bad exit status: 2)`
`ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl88x2bu: 5.6.1 not found`
`Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.13-050813-generic (x86_64)`
`Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2bu/5.6.1/build/make.log for more information.`

Comment: Did you clone a fresh copy or did you try: `cd rtl88x2bu` followed by: `git pull`? What does the referenced log say? `cat /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2bu/5.6.1/build/make.log`

Comment: I don't know what do you mean `git pull`, nor the referenced log.

Comment: First, I began since `sudo apt-get update` until `sudo dkms build -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}` because it got error. Then I asked you. Later, I deleted the folder rtl88x2bu and typed `sudo dkms status` then `sudo dkms remove rtl88x2bu/5.6.1 --all`. And finally, I began again your steps of installation and I got the same problem.

Comment: The error you quoted above clearly says: "Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2bu/5.6.1/build/make.log for more information." What exactly does it report? Find out from the terminal: `cat /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2bu/5.6.1/build/make.log` I just ran the process again on my 20.04 installation by copying and pasting each command in order and it worked perfectly, without error or warnings.

Comment: The result on the terminal, two pictures: ( https://yadi.sk/i/DPYHBs3hz8a2Zw ) and ( https://yadi.sk/i/wZ7LZKt4L7JTEQ )

Comment: Ah, haaa! The 5.6.1 version of the driver doesn't 'make' (compile) properly in your 5.8.13 kernel. Is there some reason you need 5.8.13 instead of the default 5.4.0-xx kernel version for 20.04 where it compiles correctly? Can you boot into 5.4.0-xx at the GRUB menu and try again?

Comment: I booted into 5.4.0-48-generic and it works fine. On the 5.8.13 Kernel because I tried to work Bluetooth 5.0 but thank you for supporting.

Comment: @chilli555 sudo apt install --reinstall build-essential dkms git
/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend this came up after the above instruction and Terminal had to be crashed closed same for git clone https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu.git
cd rtl88x2bu

Comment: @MarkThomas Please start your own new question.